# Finding a specific serial COM port in pySerial (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyserial

I have a script built (Windows 7, Python 2.7) to list the serial ports but I'm looking for a device with a specific name.
My script:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print(p)
```

This returns:

```
COM3 - Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)
COM6 - MyCDCDevice (COM6)
COM1 - Communications Port (COM1)
>>>
```

Great! However, I want this script to automatically pick out MyCDCDevice from the bunch and connect to it. 
I tried:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if 'MyCDCDevice' in p:
        print(p)
        // do connection stuff to COM6
```

But that doesn't work. I suspect because p isn't exactly a string, but an object of some sort?

Anyways, what's the correct way to go about this?

Thanks!!

Comment: add `else: print "NOT:",repr(p)` where you have your comment (which is not a python comment...but i suspect you knew that)

Comment: It would be `str(p)`, but you can also use [`p.description`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/v3.0.1/serial/tools/list_ports_common.py#L29).

Comment: I figured it would be just that simple! Thanks guys, YOU ROCK! str(p) did the trick.

Comment: In windows am facing problem even with import after installing pyserial, any idea on how to solve this. Error is: "ImportError: No module named tools.list_ports"

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is very old, but I thought I would post my findings since there was no 'accepted' answer (better late than never).

[This documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) helped with determining members of the object, and I eventually came to this solution.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if 'MyCDCDevice' in p.description:
        print(p)
        # Connection to port
        s = serial.Serial(p.device)
```

Answer (score 5):

To further extend on this, I've found it safer to make use of the PID and VID of the device in question.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

# FTDI FT232 device (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)
pid="0403"
hid="6001"
my_comm_port = None

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

for p in ports:
    if pid and hid in p.hwid:
       my_comm_port = p.device
```

Better still, you can use the serial number of the device for the lookup, just in case you have 2 of the same device plugged in.

([Source](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serial.tools.list_ports.grep`, which searches all of the description fields for you. For example:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports

try:
    cdc = next(list_ports.grep("MyCDCDevice"))
    # Do connection stuff on cdc
except StopIteration:
    print "No device found"
```

If that doesn't work, you may try adding a `*` to the end of the string you pass to `grep` in case there are extra characters in the descriptor.